# Working with Visual Studios C++ manifest files

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, manifest

I have written some code that makes use of an open source library to do some of the heavy lifting. This work was done in linux, with unit tests and cmake to help with porting it to windows. There is a requirement to have it run on both platforms.

I like Linux and I like cmake and I like that I can get visual studios files automatically generated. As it is now, on windows everything will compile and it will link and it will generate the test executables.

However, to get to this point I had to fight with windows for several days, learning all about manifest files and redistributable packages.

As far as my understanding goes:

With VS 2005, Microsoft created Side By Side dlls. The motivation for this is that before, multiple applications would install different versions of the same dll, causing previously installed and working applications to crash (ie "Dll Hell"). Side by Side dlls fix this, as there is now a "manifest file" appended to each executable/dll that specifies which version should be executed.

This is all well and good. Applications should no longer crash mysteriously. However...

Microsoft seems to release a new set of system dlls with every release of Visual Studios. Also, as I mentioned earlier, I am a developer trying to link to a third party library. Often, these things come distributed as a "precompiled dll". Now, what happens when a precompiled dll compiled with one version of visual studios is linked to an application using another version of visual studios?

From what I have read on the internet, bad stuff happens. Luckily, I never got that far - I kept running into the "MSVCR80.dll not found" problem when running the executable and thus began my foray into this whole manifest issue.

I finally came to the conclusion that the only way to get this to work (besides statically linking everything) is that all third party libraries must be compiled using the same version of Visual Studios - ie don't use precompiled dlls - download the source, build a new dll and use that instead.

Is this in fact true? Did I miss something?

Furthermore, if this seems to be the case, then I can't help but think that Microsoft did this on purpose for nefarious reasons.

Not only does it break all precompiled binaries making it unnecessarily difficult to use precompiled binaries, if you happen to work for a software company that makes use of third party proprietary libraries, then whenever they upgrade to the latest version of visual studios - your company must now do the same thing or the code will no longer run.

As an aside, how does linux avoid this? Although I said I preferred developing on it and I understand the mechanics of linking, I haven't maintained any application long enough to run into this sort of low level shared libraries versioning problem.

Finally, to sum up: Is it possible to use precompiled binaries with this new manifest scheme? If it is, what was my mistake? If it isn't, does Microsoft honestly think this makes application development easier?

Update - A more concise question: **How does Linux avoid the use of Manifest files?**

Comment: I don't understand why this question has been voted down...it seems to be thought out...and while, slightly Microsoft bashy from frustration, well tempered and willing to reason.

Comment: I'm guessing that it's a lot of text to read!  If the question were more concise he may have better luck.

Comment: When a question's title asks "is x trying to be evil?" don't be surprised when people downvote it. :)

Comment: I suppose thats true. On contemplating this more, it is a rather round about way to go about being evil. "Never attribute to malice...". A more concise question: How does linux avoid needing manifest files.

Comment: Windows never needed manifests before VS2003 either. They're a bodge to get round dll hell, mainly by introducing a different problem - dll proliferation :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

All components in your application must share the same runtime. When this is not the case, you run into strange problems like asserting on delete statements.

This is the same on all platforms. It is not something Microsoft invented.

You may get around this 'only one runtime' problem by being aware where the runtimes may bite back.
This is mostly in cases where you allocate memory in one module, and free it in another.

```
a.dll
    dllexport void* createBla() { return malloc( 100 ); }

b.dll
    void consumeBla() { void* p = createBla(); free( p ); }
```

When a.dll and b.dll are linked to different rumtimes, this crashes, because the runtime functions implement their own heap.

You can easily avoid this problem by providing a destroyBla function which must be called to free the memory.

There are several points where you may run into problems with the runtime, but most can be avoided by wrapping these constructs.

For reference :

- don't allocate/free memory/objects across module boundaries
- don't use complex objects in your dll interface. (e.g. std::string, ...)
- don't use elaborate C++ mechanisms across dll boundaries. (typeinfo, C++ exceptions, ...)
- ...

But this is not a problem with manifests.

A manifest contains the version info of the runtime used by the module and gets embedded into the binary (exe/dll) by the linker. When an application is loaded and its dependencies are to be resolved, the loader looks at the manifest information embedded in the exe file and uses the according version of the runtime dlls from the WinSxS folder. You cannot just copy the runtime or other modules to the WinSxS folder. You have to install the runtime offered by Microsoft. There are MSI packages supplied by Microsoft which can be executed when you install your software on a test/end-user machine.

So install your runtime before using your application, and you won't get a 'missing dependency' error.

---

(Updated to the "How does Linux avoid the use of Manifest files" question)

**What is a manifest file?**

Manifest files were introduced to place disambiguation information next to an existing executable/dynamic link library or directly embedded into this file.

This is done by specifying the specific version of dlls which are to be loaded when starting the app/loading dependencies.

(There are several other things you can do with manifest files, e.g. some meta-data may be put here)

**Why is this done?**

The version is not part of the dll name due to historic reasons. So "comctl32.dll" is named this way in all versions of it. (So the comctl32 under Win2k is different from the one in XP or Vista). To specify which version you really want (and have tested against), you place the version information in the "appname.exe.manifest" file (or embed this file/information).

**Why was it done this way?**

Many programs installed their dlls into the system32 directory on the systemrootdir. This was done to allow bugfixes to shared libraries to be deployed easily for all dependent applications. And in the days of limited memory, shared libraries reduced the memory footprint when several applications used the same libraries.

This concept was abused by many programmers, when they installed all their dlls into this directory; sometimes overwriting newer versions of shared libraries with older ones. Sometimes libraries changed silently in their behaviour, so that dependent applications crashed.

This lead to the approach of "Distribute all dlls in the application directory".

**Why was this bad?**

When bugs appeared, all dlls scattered in several directories had to be updated. (gdiplus.dll) In other cases this was not even possible (windows components)

**The manifest approach**

This approach solves all problems above. You can install the dlls in a central place, where the programmer may not interfere. Here the dlls can be updated (by updating the dll in the WinSxS folder) and the loader loads the 'right' dll. (version matching is done by the dll-loader).

**Why doesn't Linux have this mechanic?**

I have several guesses. (This is really just guessing ...)

- Most things are open-source, so recompiling for a bugfix is a non-issue for the target audience
- Because there is only one 'runtime' (the gcc runtime), the problem with runtime sharing/library boundaries does not occur so often
- Many components use C at the interface level, where these problems just don't occur if done right
- The version of libraries are in most cases embedded in the name of its file.
- Most applications are statically bound to their libraries, so no dll-hell may occur.
- The GCC runtime was kept very ABI stable so that these problems could not occur.

Comment: What do you mean that they must share the same runtime? I suppose in linux, all shared objects should link to the same standard c lib, and I have no idea what would happen if they didnt.

However, Manifest files are a whole microsft "invention" that seem somewhat unnecessary.

I wish comments longer

Comment: 'different runtimes' generally mean "debug or release". the memory allocators are different, so alloc in a.dll, pass the memory to b.dll will crash your app if they are different. The solution is always to alloc and free the mem in the same dll. Then you have no problems.

Comment: **(Why doesn't Linux have this mechanic?)**  Linux uses ELF which stores version information.  If you use version 2.2 of a library then your program runs with 2.3 but simply exits with 2.1 or 3.0.  Everyone uses a compatible C runtime (glibc/eglibc) with only backwards-compatible changes since 2002.  Static linking is extremely uncommon.  Library vendors are careful about changes, and DLL hell is dealt with by distro maintainers, not sysadmins.  The C++ ABI change was a pain but it's over.  When GTK 3.0 arrives it will be installed alongside GTK 2.0 so apps for both will run fine.

Answer (score 3):

If a third party DLL will allocate memory and *you* need to free it, you need the same run-time libraries. If the DLL has allocate and deallocate functions, it can be ok.

It the third party DLL uses `std` containers, such as `vector`, etc. you could have issues as the layout of the objects may be completely different.

It is possible to get things to work, but there are some limitations. I've run into both of the problems I've listed above.

Comment: why uses std containers cause memory layout different?

Comment: It the code interface uses stl, then yes! VC6 std containers are coded differently than VS2008 std which are both different from STLPort. The dll's compiled code has one definition, but your code which includes their headers then compiles that code differently. Trust me, I've seen it.

Answer (score 3):

If a third party DLL allocates memory that you need to free, then the DLL has broken one of the major rules of shipping precompiled DLL's. Exactly for this reason.

If a DLL ships in binary form only, then it should also ship all of the redistributable components that it is linked against and its entry points should isolate the caller from any potential runtime library version issues, such as different allocators. If they follow those rules then you shouldn't suffer. If they don't then you are either going to have pain and suffering or you need to complain to the third party authors.

Answer (score 1):

> I finally came to the conclusion that the only way to get this to work (besides statically linking everything) is that all third party libraries must be compiled using the same version of Visual Studios - ie don't use precompiled dlls - download the source, build a new dll and use that instead.

Alternatively (and the solution we have to use where I work) is that if the third-party libraries that you need to use all are built (or available as built) with the same compiler version, you can "just" use that version.  It can be a drag to "have to" use VC6, for example, but if there's a library you must use and its source is not available and that's how it comes, your options are sadly limited otherwise.

...as I understand it.  :)

(My line of work is not in Windows although we do battle with DLLs on Windows from a user perspective from time to time, however we do have to use specific versions of compilers and get versions of 3rd-party software that are all built with the same compiler.  Thankfully all of the vendors tend to stay fairly up-to-date, since they've been doing this sort of support for many years.)

Comment: Why static linking is safe?
Suppose the 3rd party DLL staticly linking to vc8 and your DLL staticly linking to vc9, then you try to delele an object in your DLL that was created in the 3rd patry DLL, what will happen?

Comment: @lzprgmr: It's not, and - ka-blammo!

Comment: Static linking is safe in this case because you know what the dependencies of all of the libraries you're linking are.  In other words, you wouldn't try to link two libraries that depend on different runtimes together.